# Detect facebook like button and twitter share button's onload?

Tags: twitter, facebook-like, share, facebook-social-plugins

The 3rd party buttons usually take quite a bit of time to load and having them flash in suddenly is a bit jarring to the aesthetics of the page.

I decided to hide the enclosing div and then fade it in when the buttons load. Is there a clean way to bind an onload event to the buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with facebook sdk:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
js.onload = function(){
  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.render',
    function(response) {
        doSomething();
    });
  }; 
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Look at the facebook sdk for event handling:
[Facebook Event Handling](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/)

After the SDK is loaded, you can acces the FB object.

Or read this article: [Asynchronously loading twitter, google, facebook and linked-in buttons and widgets + Ajax bonus](http://www.blackfishweb.com/blog/asynchronously-loading-twitter-google-facebook-and-linkedin-buttons-and-widgets-ajax-bonus)